# Airflow signals SIGTERM

Tags: airflow

I've got an SIGTERM error when i try to run my dag. This error doesn't appear everytime.

this is my dag

```
import datetime as dt
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.models import Variable
import subprocess
import shutil
import os
from airflow.models import DagBag, TaskInstance
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator, BranchPythonOperator
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.contrib.sensors.file_sensor import FileSensor
from airflow.operators.dagrun_operator import TriggerDagRunOperator

scriptAirflow = '/home/alexw/scriptAirflow/'
uploadPath='/apps/data/80_DATA/loading/'
receiptPath= '/apps/data/80_DATA/receipt/'

def parseFileAndRename(file):
    splitFile = file.split('_')
    baseName= splitFile[2:]
    newBaseName='_'.join(baseName)
    formatDate= newBaseName.split('-')
    baseFileName = formatDate[0].lower()
    newFormatDate = formatDate[1].split('.')[0]
    date = ''.join(newFormatDate[0:8])
    fileName=baseFileName+'-'+date+'.data'
    newFileName = os.rename(uploadPath+file, uploadPath+fileName)
    return fileName

def parseFileAndMoveIt():
    for files in os.listdir(uploadPath):
        if files.startswith('MEM') or files.startswith('FMS') and files.endswith('.csv'):
            newFileName = parseFileAndRename(files)
            for file in os.listdir(uploadPath):
                if file:
                    shutil.move(uploadPath+file, receiptPath)
                    return "run_scripts"   
                else:
                    if not file.startswith(newFileName):
                        return "no_file_to_move"
        else:
            print('No file to move', files)
            pass



def runAllScripts(*args, **kwargs):
    for file in os.listdir(receiptPath):
        if file.endswith('.data') or file.endswith('.in_progress'):
            return file





default_args = {
    'owner': 'testAirSensor',
    'start_date': dt.datetime(2020, 2, 17),
    'retries': 1,
}


dag = DAG('testAirSensor', default_args=default_args, description='airflow_testAirSensor',
        schedule_interval=None, catchup=False)


file_sensor = FileSensor(
    task_id="file_sensor",
    filepath=uploadPath,
    fs_conn_id='airflow_db',
    poke_interval=10,
    dag=dag,
)
parse_and_move = BranchPythonOperator(
    task_id='parse_and_move',
    python_callable=parseFileAndMoveIt,
    trigger_rule='none_failed',
    dag=dag,
)
no_file_to_move= TriggerDagRunOperator(
    task_id='no_file_to_move',
    trigger_dag_id='testAirSensor',
    trigger_rule='all_done',
    dag=dag,
)

run_scripts = PythonOperator(
    task_id="run_scripts",
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=runAllScripts,
    trigger_rule='all_done',
    op_args=[],
    dag=dag
)
parallel_task= DummyOperator(
    task_id='parallel_task',
    dag=dag,
)


for file in os.listdir(receiptPath):
    print('FILE', file)
    dynamicTask = BashOperator(
        task_id=file,
        bash_command='python3 '+scriptAirflow+'runShScript.py "{{ execution_date }}"',
        trigger_rule='none_failed',
        dag=dag,
    )
    rerun_dag=TriggerDagRunOperator(
        task_id='rerun_dag',
        trigger_dag_id='manuf2020_v3',
        trigger_rule='none_failed',
        dag=dag,
    )
    parallel_task.set_upstream(run_scripts)
    dynamicTask.set_upstream(parallel_task) 
    rerun_dag.set_upstream(dynamicTask)

rerun_dag=TriggerDagRunOperator(
   task_id='rerun_dag',
   trigger_dag_id='testAirSensor',
   trigger_rule='none_failed',
   dag=dag,
)

parse_and_move.set_upstream(file_sensor)
run_scripts.set_upstream(parse_and_move)
no_file_to_move.set_upstream(parse_and_move)
parallel_task.set_upstream(run_scripts)
rerun_dag.set_upstream(parallel_task)
```

with the errors

```
[2020-03-16 14:28:00,043] {taskinstance.py:941} ERROR - Received SIGTERM. Terminating subprocesses.
[2020-03-16 14:28:00,043] {bash_operator.py:140} INFO - Sending SIGTERM signal to bash process group
[2020-03-16 14:28:00,044] {helpers.py:288} INFO - Process psutil.Process(pid=2581, status='terminated') (2581) terminated with exit code None
[2020-03-16 14:28:00,045] {helpers.py:288} INFO - Process psutil.Process(pid=2699, status='terminated') (2699) terminated with exit code None
[2020-03-16 14:28:00,063] {taskinstance.py:1128} ERROR - Task received SIGTERM signal
```

I read that error occurred when, in bash operator, sub_process attribute is not created in *init*
and if on_kill is called before sub_process is created, we'll get an exception
this was causing failures. Attribute is checked to early. If someone have an idea to fix this, thank you !

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: unfortunately no, and i switch on another project, i'll come back to this

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. How is it possible to track down what causes that signal?